# ng-repeat is not working in blade file

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

When i am trying to display data in a simple page using angular JS it's working fine. Below is the code used for displaying data in a table.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Sl No</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User Email</th>
        <th>User DOB</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Status</th>

    </tr>    
    <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
        <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.lvl_user_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.lvl_user_email }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.lvl_user_dob }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.lvl_user_gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.lvl_user_status }}</td>

    </tr>      
</table>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.datas = [
    {
        "lvl_user_pk_id": 12,
        "usr_fk_id": 12,
        "lvl_user_name": "Rajat Chatargee",
        "lvl_user_email": "rajat.cat@mailinator.com",
        "lvl_user_dob": "1986-01-01",
        "lvl_user_gender": "Female",
        "lvl_user_address": "NanNAnA",
        "lvl_user_status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2015-06-04 12:36:30",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-04 12:36:30"
    },
    {
        "lvl_user_pk_id": 11,
        "usr_fk_id": 11,
        "lvl_user_name": "Jagadish jha",
        "lvl_user_email": "testuser1100@mailinator.com",
        "lvl_user_dob": "2014-01-02",
        "lvl_user_gender": "Female",
        "lvl_user_address": "Na",
        "lvl_user_status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2015-06-04 12:32:20",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-04 12:32:20"
    },
    {
        "lvl_user_pk_id": 10,
        "usr_fk_id": 9,
        "lvl_user_name": "Test User",
        "lvl_user_email": "usertest@mailinator.com",
        "lvl_user_dob": "2015-01-01",
        "lvl_user_gender": "Female",
        "lvl_user_address": "Test Address",
        "lvl_user_status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2015-06-04 12:30:58",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-04 12:30:58"
    }
]
});

</script>

But when I am using the same code in blade file of  my laravel application  to display data in table format it's not working.
```

Please some body help me to fix this issue.

Below is the blade file code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.datas = [
    {
        "lvl_user_pk_id": 12,
        "usr_fk_id": 12,
        "lvl_user_name": "Rajat Chatargee",
        "lvl_user_email": "rajat.cat@mailinator.com",
        "lvl_user_dob": "1986-01-01",
        "lvl_user_gender": "Female",
        "lvl_user_address": "NanNAnA",
        "lvl_user_status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2015-06-04 12:36:30",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-04 12:36:30"
    },
    {
        "lvl_user_pk_id": 11,
        "usr_fk_id": 11,
        "lvl_user_name": "Jagadish jha",
        "lvl_user_email": "testuser1100@mailinator.com",
        "lvl_user_dob": "2014-01-02",
        "lvl_user_gender": "Female",
        "lvl_user_address": "Na",
        "lvl_user_status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2015-06-04 12:32:20",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-04 12:32:20"
    },
    {
        "lvl_user_pk_id": 10,
        "usr_fk_id": 9,
        "lvl_user_name": "Test User",
        "lvl_user_email": "usertest@mailinator.com",
        "lvl_user_dob": "2015-01-01",
        "lvl_user_gender": "Female",
        "lvl_user_address": "Test Address",
        "lvl_user_status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2015-06-04 12:30:58",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-04 12:30:58"
    }
]
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">         
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Sl No</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User Email</th>
        <th>User DOB</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr> 

    <tr scope='' ng-repeat="data in datas">
        <td></td>
        <td>@{{data.lvl_user_name}}</td>
        <td>@{{data.lvl_user_email}}</td>
        <td>@{{data.lvl_user_dob}}</td>
        <td>@{{data.lvl_user_gender}}</td>
        <td>@{{data.lvl_user_status}}</td>            
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Both Laravel and Angular use double curly braces.

{{ variableName }}

So you will have to resolve this conflict first.

To change the braces for Angular you can use the code below:

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
    });
```

Or to change Blade Tags, place the following code in your routes.php

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');        // for variables and all other things
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');   // for escaped data
```

Comment: I am using @ symbol to over come the conflict.

Comment: I haven't really used the @ symbol to resolve conflicts, Sorry I'm unaware of that.

Comment: @MANOJ, I suggest that you also delete your compiled views which are located at `storage/framework/views`. Delete everything except .gitignore file.